# Drawing FCurve with Empty

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to archive drawing a FCurve with an Empty.

All works as expected, except that i have written a conditonal script that deletes the spline at the end of the frame range, sometimes its working as expected and sometimes not (reloading the Blend file sometimes fixes it)

For me it has something to do with the order of execution but I'm not sure about it, maybe its an other issue.

[image]

DeleteSplines.py:

```
if x:
    curves = bpy.data.curves
    #objects = bpy.data.objects
    # scene = bpy.context.scene

    obj = bpy.data.objects['FCurve']
    cu = obj.data  # the curve
    spli = cu.splines
    spli.clear()
    print("Splines deleted")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The order of execution was indeed wrong. I just put the script node after the "Curve Object Output", even if the Object input for the script is unneeded, it is required for the execution order.

[image]

It seems that the order of execution is in the non-fixed version undefined, but I'm not sure about that, I couldn't find anything in the docs about it.